# Alignment issues css

Tags: html, css

I have alignemet issues between caret and the vertical menu, please any help.. i tried float: , position .. nothing work with caret.

[image: Image link is here]

The caret should be at the top of the page.

How can I change the background of the caret like to be like lines similar to mobile application.

```
<style>
   nav {
      /* Repeating background image */
      background: url(http://weebtutorials.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/a.png); 
      width:210px;
      margin:20px;
   }
   nav ul {
      /* Removes bullet points */
      list-style:none;
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
   }
   nav ul li {
      /* Any child positioned absolutely will be positioned relative to this */
      position:relative;
   }
   nav a {
      color:#e8e8e8;
      padding:12px 0px;
      /* Fill all available horizontal space */
      display:block;
      /* Remove underline */
      text-decoration:none;
      /* 
      New CSS3 animations:
      apply transition to background property, taking 1s to change it 
      */
      transition:background 1s;
      -moz-transition:background 1s;
      -webkit-transition:background 1s;
      -o-transition:background 1s;
      font-family:tahoma;
      font-size:13px;
      text-transform:uppercase;
      padding-left:20px;
   }
   nav a:hover {
      /* 
      RGBA background for t
      background: RGBA(255,255,255,0.05);
      color:#fff;
   }
   nav a:hover span {
      background: #7d2c41;
      transform:rotate(90deg);
      -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
      -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
   }
   nav ul li:hover ul {
      display:block;
   }
   nav ul ul {
      position:absolute;
      left:210px;
      top:0;
      border-top:1px solid #e9e9e9;
      display:none;
   }
   nav ul ul li {
width:200px;
background:#f1f1f1;
border:1px solid #e9e9e9;
border-top:0;
}
nav ul ul li a {
color:#a8a8a8;
font-size:12px;
text-transform:none;
}
nav ul ul li a:hover {
color:#929292;
}
nav span {
width:12px;
height:12px;
background:#fff;
display:inline-block;
float:left;
margin-top:3px;
margin-right:20px;
position:relative;
transition:all 0.5s;
-moz-transition:all 0.5s;
-o-transition:all 0.5s;
-webkit-transition:all 0.5s;
}
nav span:before {
content:"";
width:12px;
height:2px;
background:#3a3b3b;
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:5px;
 }
nav span:after {
content:"";
width:2px;
height:12px;
background:#3a3b3b;
position:absolute;
left:5px;
position:top;
}

.caret-right {

border-left: 20px solid transparent;
border-right:20px solid transparent;
border-top: 20px solid #fff;
margin-right: 160px;
margin-top: 0px"
position: top;
float:right;
display: inline-block;

        }
</style>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
<ul>
    <li class="current"><a href="{% url 'home' %}"><span></span> Home </a></li>
    <li> <a href="{% url 'backtesting' %}"><span></span>AI assisted backtesting </a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="{% url 'beststock' %}"><span></span>Best stocks to trade today </a></li>
    <li> <a href="{% url 'freedata' %}"><span></span>Get free data </a></li>

</ul>
</nav>
<div class="btn-group cust-dropdown pull-right">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle cust-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="{% url 'aboutus' %}">About us</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url 'documentation' %}">Documentation</a>
</li>
                <li><a href="{% url 'pricing' %}">Pricing</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url 'contactus' %}">Contact us</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a></li>
            </ul>
   </div>
```

Comment: where is your html?

Comment: Pure CSS won't really help anyone that much. We need to see how your divs are structured. post your HTML code.

Comment: Could you share your html code

Comment: where is the caret-right html element?

Comment: <div class="btn-group cust-dropdown pull-right">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle cust-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span>

Comment: so where is it? all I see is "caret" not "caret-right". You have "caret-right" selector in css, but no such element in html with that class

Comment: @Faraha Please select an or up-vote helpful answers since they helped you resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Please make a working fiddle. Or you can try this,

```css
.caret-right{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: You sure meant "float: right" while "position: absolute"? Not "right: 0" instead?

Comment: html posted now

Answer (score 0):

To move the `button` to the top right, you can:

```
.cust-dropdown{
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  right:10px;
}
```

And now to add the burger menu icon, your button would look like:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle cust-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: Thank youu !! you resolved my problem .. Thanks a lot

Comment: but when i click on the button the list is very away from the button.. do you know why?

Comment: to arrive to the top of the page i need to put :
.cust-dropdown{
    border-left: 2px solid transparent;
    border-right:2px solid transparent;
    border-top: 2px solid #fff;
    position:absolute;
    top:-120px;
    right:10px;
}

Comment: @Faraha Hmm, It would be great if you could create a demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/) :)

Answer (score 0):

you have syntax error on margin top semicolon & quote mark and position value

this is your code

```
.caret-right {
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right:20px solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid #fff;
    margin-right: 160px;
    margin-top: 0px"
    position: top;
    float:right;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

should be

```
.caret-right {
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right:20px solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid #fff;
    margin-right: 160px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: it is a mistake writing here not in the code .. i copy paste what you write and nothing change

Answer (score 0):

You can play with this and come up with a design that fits your site..

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/u00v1yer/

- Hamburger positioned with absolute.
- Icon within hamburger also positioned/centered with absolute.
- Make sure hanmurger is within a container that has at least `position:relative;`
- Control the 3 bars width by adjusting their margin.

```css
.hamburglar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.hamburglar-line {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 6px 0;
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 50%, 0.5);
  }
.hamburglar-line:nth-child(2) {
  margin: 0;
}
.hamburglar .fa {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 36px;
  color: hsla(0, 0%, 80%, 0.7);
}

.hamburglar .hamburglar-line,
.hamburglar .fa { transition: all 0.2s linear; }
.hamburglar:hover .hamburglar-line { background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 50%, 1); }
.hamburglar:hover .fa {   color: hsla(0, 0%, 80%, 1); }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="hamburglar">
  <div class="hamburglar-line"></div>
  <div class="hamburglar-line"></div>
  <div class="hamburglar-line"></div>
  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: how can i add list to this .. to see it on click

Comment: @Faraha There are ways to do it with pure css/html but it can get tricky and limited. Look into using jQuery, it makes things really simple when you get onto it and it's pretty easy to learn. A simple 'on/off switch' added to a display: none element is all you need to start with for a simple hidden list that appears on click. Research jQuery methods .toggle, .addClass, .removeClass, .animate, .hide, .show. Also check out CSS transition.